# Android List<> Save new objects which are equal to previous object

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

So I'm trying to add Custom Objects(Members) to

```
final List<Member[]> membersAdded = new ArrayList<>();
```

By calling this method

```
 public void AddMember(Member member) {
    member.setAmountInShare(bcAmount);
    Member[] x = new Member[]{member};
    membersAdded.add(x);
    membersAddedCounter++;
    addAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if(membersAdded.get(0)[0] == membersAdded.get(membersAdded.size()-1)[0]){
        Log.d("Test", "same "+(membersAdded.size()-1));
    }

    if (membersAdded.size() > 0) hintTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else hintTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

The list hold an Array of the object(Member) so I can add more objects in the array when I need to.
So Let's I have 5 objects,

```
Member member1 = new Member();
Member member2 = new Member();
Member member3 = new Member();
Member member4 = new Member();
Member member5 = new Member();
```

when I add call

```
AddMember(member1)
```

the log returns same because they're but when I do this

```
AddMember(member1)
AddMember(member2)
AddMember(member3)
AddMember(member4)
AddMember(member5)
AddMember(member1)
```

The log returns
on first run
same
and on the last run
same

What's wrong here?

Comment: Technicaly nothing is wrong. You add `member1` first so when you call it at the end, it checks `membersAdded.get(0)[0] == membersAdded.get(membersAdded.size()-1)[0]` which is true. Since the first member you added is `member1` and the current is `member1`. What are you trying to achieve ? And why do you need an array of member in your list if you never have multiple members on your array nor your list ?

Comment: Well it a simple row for recyclerview but it has the feature to combine multiple rows into one bigger row, I know the first time it returns same which IK why but when I add the same object another time it still returns same, For some reason I think the it is not working according Pass by value but pass by reference.

Comment: First forget about Pass By Value or Pass By Reference, Java is ALWAYS Pass By Value but that's not the point. Again like I told you in my previous comment, when you add `member1` the first time, it creates a new array with `member1` in it. After that it checks if other members are equals which they are not, and when you add (again) `member1` you check that `membersAdded.get(0)[0]` (so the first element added in your list which is `member1`) is equal to `membersAdded.get(membersAdded.size()-1)[0]` which is the last item added `member1`. This is the same object so they are equal.

Comment: You create `Member member1 = new Member();` wherever you pass this object it will still be `member1`, whether or not you put it in a list of array or anything else. You are not creating a new object you are using the same one.

Comment: "*The list hold an Array of the object(Member) so I can add more objects in the array when I need to.*" are you sure? Your array is created via `Member[] x = new Member[]{member};` which means its length is 1, and length of arrays never changes so you don't have more place to *add* new element, but eventually *replace* existing one. If you need array which can grow along with number of elements added to it use List instead.

Comment: Hey, I managed to solved the problem, I'm gonna answer my own question Philppe B.

Comment: Pshemo, the array is recreated when the row needs to add more element to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was adding rows by selecting row items from another list Like this,

```
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Member x = memberList.get(position);
        x.setPositionInBc(counter);
        counter++;
        bcAddMembersFragment.AddMember(x);
        Toast.makeText(bcAddMembersFragment.getContext(), "Member Added", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
```

For some reason (Member x) is taking a reference of the object from the 2nd list so I made a new constructor of the Member object and vollah.

What I did to solve the problem is

```
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Member x = memberList.get(position);
        Member tempMember = new Member(x.getId(), x.getName(), x.getContactNumber(), 
            x.getStatus().toString());
        tempMember.setPositionInBc(counter);
        counter++;
        bcAddMembersFragment.AddMember(tempMember);
        Toast.makeText(bcAddMembersFragment.getContext(), "Member Added", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
```

Comment: This is not for some reason. Please try to understand what we are telling you. When you create an object and put it in a list or an array it doesn't create a new instance of this object, it stores the instance of your object in your list or array. So if you decide to store the same object in your array or list, this will be the same object. If you want to store a different object from the values of your previous one, you can do like you did here.

Comment: Member member = new Member(); Member member1 = member; Member2 = member, I thought If I change member1 it wouldn't effect member2 but it did.

Comment: Of course you have **_one_** instance of `Member` -> `Member member = new Member();` so if you do `Member member1 = member;`, `member1` is now the object `member`. So if you modify `member1` you modify `member` because they are the **_same_**. Same for `member2`, you never create a new instance for `member1` or `member2` you just say that `member1` and `member2` are `member`. If you did `Member member1 = new Member();`, `member1` and `member` would be **_different_**.

Comment: Ah nice, that's a pretty good explanation, thanks mate.

Comment: @PhilippeB. I finally understand what you mean, I've switched to Angular 11-12 and I'm rocking it, thanks man.